# Signature verification issue in updating Azure SDK for Visual studio 2013 update 5

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I am trying to install Azure SDK. I have visual studio 2013 Update 5. I am updating through visual studio as follows. Tool > EXtensions & Updates > Updates > Microsoft Azure SDK 2.8.1 > Update. But I am getting an error box saying some products did not install as the file failed signature verification. [image]

Has anybody else faced this? Why signature verification is failing for some files & how to fix it?